# Restrict users from creating certain title

Tags: 7

I want to restrict the users from creating contents with certain title. I require the following functionality.

**Example :**

1. Prevent users from creating a content with title, say **ABCD**
2. Prevent users from creating a content which has the words, say **ABCD** in the title.

Is there a module for this purpose. I'm new to drupal and I searched drupal.org but couldn't find a module. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into using a combination of [automatic nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle), [field_validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) and [clientside validation](http://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation). Basically once you have those three installed you can create a new text field on your content type which you will use as the title. In the validation settings for that field you can then set it up to not accept certain rules ([see this post](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/module-monday-field-validation)). Under the edit section of the content type you can set auto nodetitles to use your new field (and hide the title field) as your title.

Answer (score 1):

**Module Approach**

The [Field Validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module may be able to help you validate titles and content.

**Module Setup Details**

*Create a Black List*

You could add a new 'blacklist' of words against a field if you have a specific list.  This would knock out the use of **ABCD** as noted in both cases you listed above.

*Use REGEX*

You could use REGEX to validate against one or both of the cases you listed above.

[Lullabot](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/module-monday-field-validation) has some good introductory information to this module as well.

**Advanced**

If you're looking to get your hands dirty you could add a validation function to any form using hook_form_alter().

You can use the [Form API Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826) as an intro into custom validation.  Specifically, see the *Validating Forms* section.